# When resolving physics problems involving forces, when should I use signs for the forces vs leave them appear when doing the math?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

In some physics problems that involve finding a second force given the total force and a first force, I've seen people's solution "letting" the math give you the sign of the missing force

Let's say we know the intuitively, or given a graph, we know that the second missing force is in the direction of the negative X-axis, while the first is in the positive direction and the net force is in the positive direction as well.

Sometimes, they don't make any assumption about the sign of the second force and solve with:

$ F_{net} = F_{1} + F_{2} $

Leaving $ F_{2} $ with a negative sign and confirming the direction of the force.

However, in some problems, you can see the direction of that second force. One could use:

$ F_{net} = F_{1} - F_{2} $

And I understand that what you will get is the magnitude of the force $ F_{2} $ as you already plugged in the direction of the force.

I'm wondering if there's any strategy or tips for when is good to use the sign of the force in the equations and when is better to leave the signs appears when doing the math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to always consider all the forces as sign-less magnitudes and add signs in front of them. As in your latter example. Then, if you ever get a negative result for one of the magnitudes, you know that your initial guess of sign was wrong. This is what is done in equations like $$F_{net}=F_1+F_2-F_3-F_4+F_5-F_6+\cdots$$

But I would only do this when I really have a good overview of all terms. In general I would add up all terms and let the sign be included in the term itself. Then when solving for a term, if it is negative I know that it is **opposite to all the others**. This is often slightly easier to do as you don't have to worry about directions when setting up the math. Then it is much simpler to explain what to do in for example Netwon's laws:

$$F_{net}=\sum F=F_1+F_2+F_3+F_4+F_5+\cdots$$

Just add all forces, with their signs, and there's not much more to worry about. It is a cleaner method of writing and explaining math in general, imo.

Plus this way of writing works for not just scalar addition but also vector addition, where signs do not make much sense/are defined differently. Having one notation/convention covering all cases is often pedagogically smarter than having slightly different conventions for special cases, if they don't add any significant pedagogical improvement that is.

Answer (score 2):

Forces are vectors, so best to describe them as such, then you have no doubt how to write them as $ \\\vec{F_{net}}=\vec{F_1}+\vec{F_2}$  then with the magnitude of F $ |\vec{F}|=F $ and you can write $ F_{net}=F_1-F_2 $ especially if you go to more than 1 dimension you should always use vectors.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon @Steeven answer, there are many circumstances where you do not know the signs of unknown forces (or moments/torques), in which case you may have to assume a sign and the "math" will reveal the proper sign, *provided the math is based on a consistent set of rules or requirements.*

For example, in statics problems the requirement for static equilibrium is the sum of the forces are zero, or $\sum F=0$, and the sum of the moments are zero, or $\sum M=0$. You can assume directions for the unknown forces as long as you are consistent with giving the forces signs with respect to the chosen coordinate system. When summing the moments using the unknown forces you need to be consistent with the sign of the moment, e.g., all clockwise moments are positive and all counterclockwise moments are negative.

The analogous situation occurs in circuit analysis and the application of Kirchhoff's laws. In loop or mesh analysis you can arbitrarily assign a direction for the loop currents. But when applying $\sum V=0$ you need to be consistent with respect to assigning the polarities of the unknown voltages across the circuit components due to the loop currents, in order for the math to correctly reveal whether or not you picked the correct direction for the loop current.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the other answers; you are voicing a valid concern.

I want to take a closer look why this issue arises at all.
Imagine a notation convention where the act of combining factors and the act of assigning a sign are separate.

Let me borrow a symbol from the set of logical operators: the symbol $\wedge$ stands for 'and'.

$F_{net} = F_1 \ \wedge \ F_2 $

With such a notation it doesn't make sense to prepend a sign to either $F_1$ or $F_2$.

What happens, I believe, is this:
Let's say we want to do the following 'and' operation

$ x = 3 \wedge (-2) $

It is convention to *merge* the 'and' operation with the sign assignment operation

$x = 3 - 2 $

It seems to me this merging convention can become problematic.

There is the law of motion that when two objects are exerting a force upon each other, both changing the other object's momentum then the exerted forces are equal in magnitude, and opposite in direction.

This is often expressed as follows:

$ F_{action} = -F_{reaction} $

But to write it that way is to treat the force as a signless quantity.

So my recommendation is to try and be rigorous about it.

In equations think of the plus sign not as assignment of sign, but purely as an 'and' operator. Don't assign signs to symbols; the very purpose of a *symbol* is that it can stand for either a positive or a negative number.